# Django Chartkick library option issues

Tags: django, highcharts, django-templates, chartkick

I'm having difficulty getting Django Chartkick to work when using the library option.  The application is somewhat complex but briefly when I do not use the library option the chart renders.  When I do it does not render.

More specifically this doesn't render:

```
{% column_chart count_by_type_type with library= {"title":"Super chart",width:"400px"} %}
```

This does render

```
{% column_chart count_by_type_type %}
```

Thanks for any clues as to why and how to fix.

**Edit 20140415**

```
width:"400px"
```

should be

```
"width":"400px"
```

However, that does **not** resolve the issue.

With "width" changed the chart renders with a title and width with Google Charts.  When using Highcharts, however, there is no title.

This appears to be a bug in Django Chartkick when using Highcharts.  See https://github.com/mher/chartkick.py/issues/13 and comments.

Comment: In the first situation, you receive any errors in the console? (I mean console in a browser)

Comment: There are no errors.  Further investigation strongly suggests that this is a bug in django chartkick when using Highcharts.  The error does NOT occur when using Google Charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem was that I was using the Google Charts API not the Highcharts API.  Thanks to Mher Movsisyan the owner of Django Chartkick for a quick answer on Github.

This is his answer for the benefit of other stackoverflow users:

> The configuration formats for Google Charts and HighCharts are
>   different. You are trying to apply the Google Charts api to
>   HighCharts.
>
> In this particular example you need to use:
>
> ```
> {% pie_chart browser_stats with library={"title":{"text":"Browser Statistics, May 2013"}} %}
> ```
>
> See Highcharts API http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/title-and-subtitle

For a fuller discussion see https://github.com/mher/chartkick.py/issues/13